# Moving a certain div using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I am trying to give interval to `move()`,so that my box can move in a container but it is not working. I have listed my box class which is initialized in my main index page inside `<script>`.The box is created but it is not moving.

```
//class to add new box object in a container
function Box(element){
var randomx;
var randomy;
var movex;
var movey;
this.element = element;
var divi;
var that = this;
//random number generator
this.randomGenerator = function(low,high){
    var randomgen = Math.floor((Math.random()*high)+low);
    return randomgen;
}
//initializing the variables
this.initial = function(){
    divi = document.createElement('div');
    divi.className = "box";
    randomx = that.randomGenerator(0,950);
    randomy = that.randomGenerator(0,350);
    movex = that.randomGenerator(6,12);
    movey = that.randomGenerator(6,12);
    var maine = that.element;
    maine.appendChild(divi);
} 
//to check for the boundary of the box
this.checkBoundary = function(){
if(randomx>=(950)){
    movex =-(that.randomGenerator(6,12));
    console.log("error1");
}
if(randomx<=0){
    movex=(that.randomGenerator(6,12));
    console.log("error2");
}
if(randomy>=(350)){
    movey= -(that.randomGenerator(6,12));
    console.log("error3");
}
if(randomy<=0){
    movey=(that.randomGenerator(6,12));
    console.log("error4");
}
}
this.move = function(){
    divi.style["left"] = randomx + 'px';
    divi.style["top"] = randomy + 'px';
    that.checkBoundary();
    randomx += movex;
    randomy += movey;
    console.log("randomx =",randomx);
    console.log("randomy =",randomy);
}
//function to initialize other functions
this.init = function(){
    that.initial();
    setInterval(that.move(),10);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the class `box` position different from `static`?

Comment: yes it is different every time i refresh my page!

Comment: I meant css property `position`. Do you have `position: relative` or `position: absolute` set on the css class `box`?

Comment: And how are you using the `Box` constructor? Are you calling `init` after you construct it?

Comment: `var randomgen = Math.floor((Math.random()*high)+low);` shouldn't this be `var randomgen = Math.floor((Math.random()*(high-low))+low);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `setInterval();` expects a function as the first argument: `setInterval(function() { that.move(); }, 10);`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but the movement is not so smooth, any idea how can i make it smooth?

Comment: Check out this post: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/